# Cannot Get Bootstrap calendar to load on my page. Using Wordpress. Java Script Errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, calendar

I am trying to get the calendar to just load on the page. I am on a WordPress site. I am getting some errors on the console. I will add them below and my code.

My links to the java script are in my footer, just before body close tag.

```
    JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1
    jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
    send @ jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5
    ajax @ jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5
    loader @ calendar.js:968
    (anonymous) @ calendar.js:992
    onBeforeEventsLoad @ calendar.js:145
    Calendar._loadEvents @ calendar.js:990
    Calendar.view @ calendar.js:787
    Calendar @ calendar.js:401
    $.fn.calendar @ calendar.js:1302
    (anonymous) @ app.js:36
    (anonymous) @ app.js:87
    VM1007:1 GET http://dev.visitsi.com.php56-26.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/events.json.php?…0&utc_offset_from=360&utc_offset_to=300&browser_timezone=America%2FChicago 404 (Not Found)
    (anonymous) @ VM1007:1
    send @ jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5
    ajax @ jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5
    loader @ calendar.js:968
    (anonymous) @ calendar.js:992
    onBeforeEventsLoad @ calendar.js:145
    Calendar._loadEvents @ calendar.js:990
    Calendar.view @ calendar.js:787
    Calendar @ calendar.js:401
    $.fn.calendar @ calendar.js:1302
    (anonymous) @ app.js:36
    (anonymous) @ app.js:87
    VM1007:1 GET http://dev.visitsi.com.php56-26.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/tmpls/month.html?_=1499869197406 404 (Not Found)
    (anonymous) @ VM1007:1
    send @ jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5
    ajax @ jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5
    Calendar._loadTemplate @ calendar.js:1020
    Calendar._render @ calendar.js:427
    Calendar.view @ calendar.js:788
    Calendar @ calendar.js:401
    $.fn.calendar @ calendar.js:1302
    (anonymous) @ app.js:36
    (anonymous) @ app.js:87
    calendar.js:461 Uncaught TypeError: this.options.templates[this.options.view] is not a function
        at Calendar._render (calendar.js:461)
        at Calendar.view (calendar.js:788)
        at new Calendar (calendar.js:401)
        at init.$.fn.calendar (calendar.js:1302)
        at app.js:36
        at app.js:87
    Calendar._render @ calendar.js:461
    Calendar.view @ calendar.js:788
    Calendar @ calendar.js:401
    $.fn.calendar @ calendar.js:1302
    (anonymous) @ app.js:36
    (anonymous) @ app.js:87
    calendar:978 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    calendar:992 Uncaught TypeError: date_input.datepicker is not a function
        at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (calendar:992)
        at c (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3)
        at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3)
        at Function.ready (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3)
        at HTMLDocument.H (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3)
    (anonymous) @ calendar:992
    c @ jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3
    fireWith @ jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3
    ready @ jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3
    H @ jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3




 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()?>/components/bootstrap3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()?>/components/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()?>/components/jstimezonedetect/jstz.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()?>/js/calendar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()?>/js/app.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    var calendar = $("#calendar").calendar( {
        tmpl_path: "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()?>/tmpls/",
        //events_source: '/calendar-events.php',
        events_source: function () { return []; }
        modal_title : function (e) { return e.title }
    });         
</script>
```

Comment: Read the tag for Java.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: I thought that is what I did? I added the code. Added the errors, that I am getting. I wrote a concise summary of the problem I am having. What did I do wrong in asking for help?